# How to connect to local SSAS Installation

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssas

I'm very new to SSAS and I've downloaded the developer edition of SSAS to deploy a local cube to it. I've opened the port 2383 and I wrote down the following during my installation:

```
Instance
MSSQLSERVER
Instance ID
MSAS15.MSSQLSERVER
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.DAVIDCUBE
```

How would I connect now in SSMS? When trying the above string `C:\...` I get an 'invalid string'. What would be the correct way to connect?

[image]

Comment: Server Name is the host name of the server instance, not a folder path

Comment: @squillman I see -- is that doing `> hostname` in the command prompt?

Comment: I think you need to write your server name of SSAS to the Server Name box https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/connect-from-client-applications-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions

Comment: @David542 Yes, that should give you the proper name to use.  As long as you run that on the machine where your SSAS instance is running :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not very sure about the Instance Name.
You could click the drop down sign at the right side. Choose

Then double click the server name on the prompt out Browse For Server window.